# QGIS: copying a value from one row to another one in the attribute table?

Tags: qgis-3

I'm trying to replace the values of the column A and B by the value of the row 1 and row 2 of column C. (`15B70C` should be replaced by `63F200` and `94JH5` by `35V145`)

How can I automate that in the simplest way possible?

[image]

Comment: A1 is no column, it is the field in row 1 on column A. Please clarify.

Comment: Ooops sorry... I should have read my question a second time before posting it !

Comment: The question is unclear. What if there is one `A1`, or three?

Comment: There are always two identical id in the case I'm working on

Comment: I still don't understand the question.  Do you want to replace *ALL* the values in column A with the value 63F200 and *ALL* the values in column B with the value 35V145?

Comment: There is another uncertainty here. For example, `A` should be replaced by `C`, but  in which row? The first one (`35V145`) or the second one (`63F200`)? Is it important?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the following script would work for you. First, select the layer and use the script in QGIS Python Editor.

```py
# get layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()
# convert features to list
features = list(layer.getFeatures())
# sort features to be sure it is sorted by id. it is crucial
features.sort(key=lambda f: f["id"])

dpr = layer.dataProvider()
# get fields' index
A = dpr.fieldNameIndex("A")
B = dpr.fieldNameIndex("B")

for i in range(0, len(features), 2):
    # make changes
    dpr.changeAttributeValues({features[i].id(): {A: features[i]["C"],
                                                  B: features[i+1]["C"]}})
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply Kadir !! Your script is almost what I'm trying to do ! I've added a new picture to clarify my question (sorry if my explanations were fuzzy !)

Comment: I guess I just have to change the last line of your code by ```features[i].id(): {B: features[i+1]["C"]}})``` right ? :)

Comment: With the edit you made, the script raise a SyntaxError:

`File "<string>", line 24
    B: features[i+1]["C"]})
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 0):

Modify the columns using the field calculator by simply putting your desired value in single paranthesis, eg. `'35V145'`. Now every field in column A reads "35V145".

Comment: The problem is that I have to do that for more than 400 hundred id :( ...
I would like to find a solution that would do the trick automatically (if it is possible)

Comment: Then you should describe your issue completely, I guess.